# Is it possible to Query Facebook users by E-mail address using FB API?

Tags: facebook, api

I spent a few hours the other day tinkering around with the Facebook API (FQL) and found it pretty cool! I saw that there is a way to query facebook users by their FB ID, but I was wondering if it's possible to query a FB user by an e-mail address.

What I would like this to do is to be able to do is...

1) query an e-mail address to see the user exists (assuming the user is set as public) -> similar to the way that you would copy and paste an e-mail address in the search box.

2) If the user exists -> fetch the first and last name.

3) else => echo "user does not exist"

If there is absolutely any way to do this, could someone point me in the right direction? I spent a few hours trying to figure this out and it was a complete fail. My guess is that it cannot be done, but I may be wrong. If anyone knows or has a simple script that they want to hand off, then that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No. The column you search by has to be "indexable" on [this table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Comment: Would it be possible to do this then? 

Query the name (first + last) (which is Indexable) and then see if the e-mail address matches?

If so, is there a simple script I can download? I've downloaded the facebook.php file + other inc/ files.

Comment: While I haven't tried that, I don't believe it will work. From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/): "Your query must also be indexable, meaning that it queries properties that are marked as indexable in the documentation below."